# me sale error (unreachable statement),no se que significa

Tags: string, condiciones, switch

pueden ayudarme porfavor xd ,me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el codigo en java ,para que ayuden porfavor :,C
NO ENTIENDO SI PUSE MAL ALGO O los valores estan mal ,quise solucionarlo iniciandolo como cero,pero al ejecutarlo quiero que me salga el resultado del pagototal del switch pero me sale cero ,por favor ayuden a este pobre hombre

```js
 public static void main(String[] args){
    int hora;
    double pagototal,descuento,pagoporhora;
    char categoria;
            String profesion="";
    categoria=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su categoria\n A:auciliar , C:contratado").charAt(0);
    profesion=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su profesion \n T : tecnico  I: ingeniero");
    hora=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora trabajada"));
    switch(categoria){
        case'A':
            if(profesion.equals('T')){
                pagoporhora= hora*23;
                descuento= 0.08*pagoporhora;
                pagototal= pagoporhora-descuento;
                        }
            if(profesion.equals('I')){
                pagoporhora=hora*30;
                descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                                        } break;
                       
        case'C':
            if(profesion.equals('T')){
                pagoporhora=hora*18;
                descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
            
                                        }
            if(profesion.equals('I')){
                pagoporhora=hora*25;
                descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                        }break;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El sueldo final es de :"+pagototal);                    
    }
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Igual si editas tu título por algo como el mensaje de error tienes mas chances de que te ayuden, checa [ask]

Comment: Además de lo mencionado en el comentario anterior, pon un título descriptivo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto tus variables categoria y profesion deberían ser de tipo char porque sólo pide ingresar una letra, en ese caso en la condicional tendrías que usar la comparación ==
Te dejo el código, todavía se puede mejorar para validar que el ingreso de teclado sean sólo los caracteres A, C,T,I y sus respectivas minúsculas

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Actividades {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int hora,pagoporhora;
        double pagototal=0,descuento;
        char categoria;
        char profesion;
        categoria=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su categoria\n A:auxiliar , C:contratado").charAt(0);
        profesion=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su profesion \n T : tecnico  I: ingeniero").charAt(0);
        hora=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora trabajada"));
        switch(categoria){
            case'A':case'a':
                if(profesion=='T'||profesion=='t'){
                    pagoporhora= hora*23;                    
                    descuento= 0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal= pagoporhora-descuento;                    
                }
                else if(profesion=='I'||profesion=='i'){
                    pagoporhora=hora*30;
                    descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                }break;

            case'C':case'c':
                if(profesion=='T'||profesion=='t'){
                    pagoporhora=hora*18;
                    descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                }
                else if(profesion=='I'||profesion=='i'){
                    pagoporhora=hora*25;
                    descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                }break;                           
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El sueldo final es de :"+pagototal);     
    }
}
```

Comment: wOW ,eres un crack bro solucionaste mi problema ,muchas gracias

Comment: @ElbaNiadoPorunMes, si una respuesta te ha sido de ayuda deberías votar a favor y si solucionó a tu pregunta deberías marcar como aceptada es la mejor forma de agradecer. Saludos

Comment: y como hago eso

Comment: Al costado de cada respuesta hay 2 flechas (arriba y abajo) la flecha de arriba es si te parece buena respuesta y el de abajo lo contrario; debajo de la flecha de abajo está el signo de check le das click y eso es todo

Answer (score 0):

tu problema actual, es que estás comparando un string en un condicional, eso es incorrecto, en este caso, debes de hacer la comparación, con la función .equals(). Dejo aquí tu código corregido.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int hora;
        double pagototal,descuento,pagoporhora;
        char categoria;
        String profesion="";
        categoria=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su categoria\n A:auciliar , C:contratado").charAt(0);
        profesion=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese su profesion \n T : tecnico  I: ingeniero");
        hora=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora trabajada"));
        switch(categoria){
            case 'A':
                if(profesion.equals('T'))
                {
                    pagoporhora= hora*23;
                    descuento= 0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal= pagoporhora-descuento;
                }
                if(profesion.equals("T"))
                {
                    pagoporhora=hora*30;
                    descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                                            
                } 
                break;
                           
            case 'C':
                if(profesion.equals('T')){
                    pagoporhora=hora*18;
                    descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                
                                            }
                if(profesion.equals('I'))
                {
                    pagoporhora=hora*25;
                    descuento=0.08*pagoporhora;
                    pagototal=pagoporhora-descuento;
                }
                break;
        
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: muchas gracias bro